http request (not https) with android plateform using micorcontroller
I see similar queestion on this web site.
I don't understand where to put manifest file or other stuff.
The web server just serve index.html, css, java script and web socket for now.
I try to read the doc and forums but I didn't understand how to proceed

You need to explain what you're trying to do better.  Are you hosting a webserver on the device?  If so, I would suggest not doing that-  Android is not a server OS, and there are better ways of doing it if its on device.  If you're running the server on another machine, then they only thing you need to do is allow clear text in your manifest (although this may not pass Google Play Store rules if you do this).
